# Is it possible to use custom view script in forms on Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Is there a way to use a custom phtml view on Zend Framework 2?

In ZF1, I've used something like this:

```
$form->setDecorators(array(array(
        'viewScript',
        array(
            'viewScript' => 'persons/custom-form.phtml',
            array('formId' => 'persons-form')
))));
```

Here's my ZF1 sample custom-form.phtml:

```
<form id="<?php echo $formId ?>">
    <?php echo $this->element->id; ?>
    <?php echo $this->element->name; ?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, although, form decorators were removed from ZF1 to ZF2. Now, to render your form with a custom partial, render that partial in your view templates just as you would any other partial and pass your form object as a view variable.

```
<?= $this->partial('your-partial', array('form' => $form)) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could work with this in your controller's action

```
$result = new ViewModel();
$result->setTemplate('somemodule/somecontroller/somescript.pthml')
return $result;
```